# Como puedo restar un valor hasta llegar a CERO solo cuando se guarde el mismo ID?

Tags: php, mysql

Me explico un poco mejor, quisiera saber como hacer un formulario que guarde horas de trabajo de un equipo al guardarse por primera vez un equipo se introduce la cantidad de horas de trabajo si se realiza algún mantenimiento se vuelve a guardar con la cantidad de horas que lleva en ese momento del mantenimiento **por ejemplo:** digamos que guarde un equipo con 2,000 horas y se averió por X cosa y en ese momento ya llevaba un total de 600 horas al realizar el mantenimiento y guardo esas 600 horas se restaría dando un total de 1,400 horas 
pero que esta resta solo se aplique cuando sea el mismo id del equipo

mi tabla se llama horas

```
Id_hora
Id_equipo
Hora
Diferencia
```

Diferencia lo pensé para que tome el resultado de la resta

```
<?php
    include "conexion.php";

    $id = $_GET['Id_list'];

    $sql ="SELECT a.Id_hora, b.Id_equipo, b.Equipo, a.Hora, a.Diferencia
           FROM hora as a
           INNER JOIN Equipos b on b.Id_equipo = a.Id_equipo
           WHERE b.Id_equipo = '$id'";
    $resu = $cone->query($sql);
    $row = $resu->fetch_assoc();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crital</title>
</head>
<body>

<center>
    <h1>Prueba de Horometro</h1>
    <form action="guar.php" method="POST">

        <a href="buscalista.php">Ingrese el Equipo</a></br ><br >
    <label>Codigo Equipo</label>
    <input type="text" name="cod" value="<?php echo $row['Id_equipo']; ?>"><br ><br >

    <label>Equipo</label>
    <input type="text" name="nom" value="<?php echo $row['Equipo']; ?>"><br ><br >


    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['Id_list'];?>"/>

    <label>Hora Incial</label>
    <input type="number" name="hora"><br ><br >



    <input type="submit" name="aceptar" value="Guardar">
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

este es el formulario donde extraigo los equipos

```
<?php
    require 'conexion.php';
    $sql ="SELECT Id_equipo, Equipo FROM Equipos";
    $resul = $cone->query($sql);                  
?>


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div class="row table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Equipo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()) 
                            {?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['Id_equipo']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['Equipo']; ?></td>
                                   <td><a href="cristal.php?Id_equipo=<?php echo $row['Id_equipo']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Agregar</span></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

y este mi php guar

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$cod= $_POST['id'];
$time = $_POST['hora'];
$time2 =  $time - $time2;





$query="insert into hora (Id_equipo, Hora, Diferencia) values('$cod','$time', '$time2')"; 
$resul= $cone->query($query);

if($resul){
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente";
    header('Location: http://'.$server.'/Dias/cristal.php');

}else{
    echo"No fue posible guardar los datos";
}
?>
```

esto es lo que tengo hasta hora pero no se como hacer eso de ir restando y identificar cuando sea el mismo ID espero me puedan ayudar y entender.

Comment: No entiendo del todo la lógica planteada aquí: *digamos que guarde un equipo con 2,000 horas y se averió por X cosa y en ese momento ya llevaba un total de 600 horas al realizar el mantenimiento y guardo esas 600 horas se restaría dando un total de 1,400*  ... yo mantendría **aparte** una tabla `equipo` sólo con los datos del equipo y una tabla que me guarde algo así como un *historial* de las veces que el equipo pasó por mantenimiento con todos los datos que se requieran incluyendo una  fecha de entrada al taller, **pero no usaría el campo calculado `Diferencia`**...

Comment: ... no lo usaría porque creo que es demasiado pobre hacer eso y explico por qué. Imaginemos que el modelo cambia y se requieren informes sobre el tiempo de garantía del equipo, algo como *¿cuántas horas de uso estuvo un equipo sin entrar en reparación durante su período de garantía?* ... siendo ese período de 1 año en unos equipos, de 2 años en otro, de 3 años en otros. ¿De qué sirve ahí el campo calculado `Diferencia`?  -De nada. No sé el alcance de tu aplicación, pero yo diseñaría algo así como un control de reparaciones en todo el sentido de la palabra que me sirva para generar informes así

Comment: Dentro de 3 años, con 10 millones de registros, el dueño de la empresa quiere saber *¿cuántos equipos del tipo electrodoméstico cumplieron su período de garantía sin pasar por el taller?*  Ufff te quiero ver cómo vas a sacar el dato. O, *¿en qué mes entraron más equipos a taller en el año 2020?* Lo que quiero decir es que las cosas evolucionan, y cuando hay un diseño pensando en esa posible evolución es mucho más fácil incorporar una nueva consulta que ponerte a modificar el modelo de datos agregando campos que debieron ser previstos en su día. No digo que lo hagas así, sólo lo dejo como idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código guardar está el problema, no entiendo por que haces un `insert` de un nuevo registro si debería ser un `update` del equipo que ya registraste. Al final esta estructura te dará dolor de cabeza si quieres hacer Data Mining. Te dejo un ejemplo comenta de cómo puede quedar.

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$cod  = $_POST['id'];
$time = $_POST['hora'];

//Primero revisamos cual es la diferencia restante con esta query
$check = "select Diferencia from hora where Id_equipo = " . $cod;

//Validamos que se haya hecho bien la consulta
if( !$res = $cone->query( $check ) ){
  echo 'Ocurrió un error en la consulta';

}else{
  //Ahora validamos que si haya campos
  if( $res->num_rows() <= 0 ){
    echo 'La consulta no retornó información';

  }else{
    //Ahora sacamos la información, en este caso la diferencia
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc( $res );
    $dif = $row['Diferencia'];

    //Ahora validamos que la diferencia no sea menor que lo que se está tratando de restar
    if( $dif < $time ){
      echo 'El equipo ' . $cod . ' no tiene las horas suficientes, tiene ' . $dif;
    }else{

      //Entonces ahora si hacemos un Update de la nueva diferencia, pero con un update, no un insert
      $query = "update hora set Diferencia = ". $time ." where Id_equipo = " . $cod;
      $cone->query( $query ); 

      //Validamos que se haya hecho bien el update
      if( $cone->affected_rows() <= 0 ){
        echo 'No fue posible actualizar la diferencia';

      }else{
        //Si se guardó bien, ahora si, redirigimos.
        echo "Datos guardados correctamente";
        header('Location: http://'.$server.'/Dias/cristal.php');
      }
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Puedes usar las partes que más te convengan, este código lo hice sin un ambiente de testing, puede que te genere un par de errores, pero nada que no puedas resolver sólo. Y te comento de igual forma que tu código tiene muchos huecos de seguridad, fácil te meten SQLInjection, pero no lo incluí por que te desviaría de tu objetivo principal.

Saludos

Comment: Tome de ejemplo tu idea amigo, y funciono gracias.